# Error with addition in MS Access one table to another?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table I have 5 columns and 5 rows, now I need to add only `AmountPaid` column of 3 rows and want to store in another table. That 3 rows contain unique code and recording to this unique code I want to join this total amount to new table.

I tried this code but not working how I except.

```
SELECT InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, SalesPerson(SELECT SalesPerson FROM 
SalesDepartment WHERE SalesDepartment.SalesPersonId=Invoice.SalesPerson) 
AS SalesPerson, Customer, OrderNumber, GrandTotal, 

AmountPaid(SELECT AmountPaid FROM Payment WHERE 
Payment.InvoiceNo=Invoice.InvoiceNo) AS AmountPaid

FROM Invoice;
```

If I remove last AmountPaid column this code working fine. But I need to add paid amount of one table and store it on another table column. How to complete this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

Subquery:

```
SELECT InvoiceNo,
       InvoiceDate,
       (SELECT SalesPerson FROM SalesDepartment WHERE SalesDepartment.SalesPersonId=Invoice.SalesPerson) AS SalesPerson,
       Customer,
       OrderNumber,
       GrandTotal,
       (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM Payment WHERE Payment.InvoiceNo=Invoice.InvoiceNo) AS totalAmountPaid
FROM Invoice;
```

Equijion:

```
SELECT InvoiceNo, 
       InvoiceDate,
       SalesPerson,
       Customer,
       OrderNumber,
       GrandTotal,
       SUM(AmountPaid) AS totalAmountPaid
FROM Invoice 
    INNER JOIN SalesDepartment ON SalesDepartment.SalesPersonId=Invoice.SalesPerson
    INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.InvoiceNo=Invoice.InvoiceNo
GROUP BY InvoiceNo
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering but both Query are same. In that Payment table 2 or more rows contain same invoice number so we need to add that total and that join in this query. How to add that ?

Comment: my bad, forgot to add the SUM() aggregate function

Comment: How to add that SUM() aggregate function give some code

Comment: Hi thanks this code working fine. But it show decimal values like 125.3 and integer valves like 654 but I need to display both decimal and integer values 125.30 & 654.00

Comment: Here's a page for [Format](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/format.php) on MSAccess. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, ya i saw but I can add that Standard Format in this query ?